# Flask app doesn't open in browser while using flask cli

Tags: flask, flask-cli

I wrote flask web which I was testing by running the server like ‘python src/run.py’

Now recently I decided to use flask cli approach.

So I did ‘export FLASK_APP=src/run.py‘

then ‘flask run‘ it work starts web app at 5000 by default but nothing opens in browser.

I do not get any error. Do I have to create FlaskGroup to create flask cli run command explicitly?

Comment: Did you actually set up routes? - I mean; there's not much we can work with in this question. - Add more code etc.

Comment: I got it working by specifying ‘--host 0.0.0.0‘

Comment: Why don't you specify that in your `run.py`?

Comment: Add code if not solved. For --host 0.0.0.0, that would be your local IP address.